# Why does the internal css style of black outline on in-focus focusable elements, not apply on click+hold?

Tags: html, css, user-agent, onfocus, outline

If you run the following demo, and click+hold(hold for 1sec before releasing the click) on the third link, you will see they get the same styles of `:focus` pseudo selector from the css(red outline).

```css
.ext:focus {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">1. Get me in focus with tab to see black outline -- Browser default </a>
<br><br>

<a class="ext" href="#">2. Get me in focus with tab to see red outline -- ext css </a>

<br><br>

<a class="ext" href="#">3. Click+hold to see red outline -- supposody gets me in focus </a>
<br><br>
<a  href="#">4. Click+hold to see black outline -- doesnt work as expected!</a>
```

My gut feeling is that when you click+hold on any focusable element, it gets that element in focus, thats why you see a red dotted outline on #3 link.

Now, then why in the fourth link when you click+hold you don't see a black outline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that when you click on a focusable element it gets *infocus* as well, but your misconception is that the browsers internally apply the following css:

```
a:focus {
  outline: 2px solid black;
}
```

In reality the browsers use the [`focus-visible`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible) css property like this:

```
a:focus-visible {
  outline: 2px solid black;
}
```

`focus-visible` is a css4 level property recently introduced by most browsers(except safari). It has been designed specifically for what have you observed. This behaviour gets even more apparent in case of input fields([check out MDN's example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible#basic_example)), where you don't have to hold the click to see the result. In the case of anchor tags `focus-visible` applies style to only those elements who've been focused through the keyboard not the mouse. It should be noted that the `button` element behaves similar to `a` element, but the `input` element treats `focus-visible` identical to `focus`, that is even on click it gets the styles mention in `input:focus-visible{...}`.

Example:

```css
input:focus-visible, button:focus-visible {
  outline: 2px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Click/tab shows outline">

<button>Only tab shows outline</button>
```

Moreover, you can inspect element in your browser and toggle element's state to `focus-visible`. You will see the following styles being applied by the user-agent(chrome):

```
a:-webkit-any-link:focus-visible {
    outline-offset: 1px;
}
user agent stylesheet
a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
user agent stylesheet
:focus-visible {
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 1px;
}
```